# Expected depth of a node in an arbitrary tree.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, expected-value, trees

I'm interested to see how the pointer jumping technique in parallel algorithms compares to sequential algorithms for finding the root of a given tree.

Specifically, I want to calculate the expected depth of random node in an arbitrary (random) tree of $n$ nodes. Suppose that the trees are labeled from $\{1,\dots, n\}$ and that thre are all rooted at $1$. I also suppose that the probability of picking a node is $\frac{1}{n}$ (uniform distribution) and the probability of picking a specific (labeled) tree $\frac{1}{n^{n-2}}$ (again uniformly distributed).

My first (and only) approach is the following (for simplicity I won't explain the symbols/notation I've used)
$$ E[D] = \sum_{T\in\mathcal{T}_n}\sum_{v\in T}p_{\mathcal{T}}(T)p_{U|\mathcal{T}}(v\ |\ T)d(v)  = \frac{1}{n^{n-1}}\sum_{T\in\mathcal{T}_n}\sum_{v\in T}d(v) $$

and since we're talking about labeled trees (suppose we label the nodes from $\{1,\dots, n\}$)
$$=\frac{1}{n^{n-1}}\sum_{T\in\mathcal{T}_n}\sum_{v=1}^nd_T(v)  
= \frac{1}{n^{n-1}}\sum_{v=1}^n\sum_{T\in\mathcal{T}_n}d_T(v)
$$

trying to continue the summation  somehow...
$$= \frac{1}{n^{n-1}}\sum_{v=1}^n \sum_{d=0}^{n-1} \sum_{T\in\mathcal{T}_n;\\d_T(v)=d}d_T(v)  = \frac{1}{n^{n-1}}\sum_{v=1}^n \sum_{d=0}^{n-1} d\cdot\left|\left\{T\ |\ T\in\mathcal{T}_n,\ d_T(v) = d \right\}\right|$$

---

Obviously I don't know what I am doing. But I have no other ideas and I wanted to include some amount of work.
Any hints, solutions or even ideas for different approaches are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by  computing the **internal  path length** of Cayley  trees. We
get from first principles the functional equation

$$T(z,u) = z \exp T(zu,u).$$

Here a term $u^q \frac{z^n}{n!}$ represents a tree on $n$ nodes having
internal path length $q.$ We require

$$n! [z^n] \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial u}
T(z, u) \right|_{u=1}
= n! [z^n] F(z).$$

We get from the functional equation

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u} T(z, u)
= z \exp T(zu, u)
\left( z \frac{\partial}{\partial z} T(z, u) (zu,u)
+ \frac{\partial}{\partial u} T(z, u) (zu,u) \right).$$

Using the tree function

$$T(z) = \sum_{n\ge 1} n^{n-1} \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

we get evaluating at $u=1$

$$F(z) = z \exp T(z) ( z T'(z) + F(z) )
= T(z) ( z T'(z) + F(z) )$$

which implies that

$$F(z) = \frac{z T(z) T'(z)}{1-T(z)}.$$

Now using Lagrange inversion by residues (Egorychev method) we seek

$$n! [z^n] F(z)
= n! [z^n] \frac{z T(z) T'(z)}{1-T(z)}
= n! \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{z^n} \frac{T(z) T'(z)}{1-T(z)}.$$

Next put $T(z)=w$ to get with $z= w \exp(-w)$

$$n! \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{\exp(nw)}{w^n} \frac{w}{1-w} 
= n! [w^{n-2}] \exp(nw) \frac{1}{1-w} 
= n! \sum_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{n^q}{q!}.$$

It follows that the average depth of a node is is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{n!}{n^n} \sum_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{n^q}{q!}.}$$

The above result can be verified using the **combstruct** package, see
below. It appears that this one  of the standard computations from the
cookbook.     The    Maple    code   below    will    produce    [OEIS
A001864](https://oeis.org/A001864), labeled as "total height of rooted
trees with  $n$ labeled nodes", so  we have confirmation of  the above
starting at $n=2$:

$$2, 24, 312, 4720, 82800, 1662024, 37665152, 952401888, \ldots.$$

```
with(combstruct);

cayley := {T=Prod(Z, Set(T))}:
cayley_ipl := {ipl(T)= Prod(0, Set(ipl(T)+size(T)))}:

Order := 13;

cayley_ipl_series :=
agfseries(cayley, cayley_ipl, labeled, z, [[u, ipl]])[T(z,u)]:

iplX := n -> n!*add(n^q/q!, q=0..n-2):

subs({u=1}, diff(cayley_ipl_series, u));
seq(iplX(n)/n!, n=0..Order-1);

seq(iplX(n), n=0..Order-1);

agfeqns(cayley, cayley_ipl, labeled, z, [[u, ipl]]);
```

Now supposing that these trees are always rooted at node one
we require

$$(n-1)! [z^{n-1}] \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial u}
\exp T(zu, u) \right|_{u=1}
= (n-1)! [z^n] \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial u}
z \exp T(zu, u) \right|_{u=1}
\\ = (n-1)! [z^n] \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial u} T(z, u)
\right|_{u=1}
\\ = (n-1)! [z^n] F(z)
= (n-1)! \sum_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{n^q}{q!}.$$

The total number of structures is given by

$$(n-1)! [z^{n-1}] \exp T(z)
= (n-1)! [z^n] z \exp T(z)
= (n-1)! [z^n] T(z)
\\ = (n-1)! \frac{n^{n-1}}{n!} = n^{n-2}$$

so the average is

$$\frac{(n-1)!}{n^{n-2}} \sum_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{n^q}{q!}.$$

The total  number of structures  also follows  by inspection --  if we
always root the tree  at node one the root marker  always stays at the
same node and we may as well not mark at all.

This    sequence    without    the    average    points    to    [OEIS
A000435](https://oeis.org/A000435),   apparently  the   sequence  that
started the OEIS.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Unfortunately I think it's too advanced for me to follow (but perhaps the problem itself is too hard for me). I'm not too familiar with generating functions and haven't really studied many combinatorics in trees/graphs. Can you point me to any resources that combine the last two?

Comment: The best reference for the above is *Analytic Combinatorics* by Flajolet and Sedgewick. I also recommend *generatingfunctionology* by Wilf.